# 64-bit Oracle Client for v8 database

Tags: oracle, client, 64-bit

Okay, here's the deal: I have a C#/.NET app accessing an Oracle 8 database, that works well on our 32-bit machines.  It works using a v.8 ODBC client, a 9i client, or a 10g XE client.  However, nothing seems to work on a 64-bit windows machine.  I did successfully install a 64-bit 11g client, only to find it refuses to talk to a v8 database, so I guess what I need is a 64-bit 10g, 9i or 8i client.  I tried 9i and 10g XE with no luck.  I have not yet tried the full 10g client.

I installed MDAC 2.8, but in the Admin Tools -> ODBC Data Source manager tool, none of those ODBC drivers show up, presumably because they are not 64 bit.  Ony MS SQL shows up.

The weird thing is that there is an old program, Impromptu by Cognos, that works fine - it seems quite able to find and use the 32-bit v8 client that is installed on the system, but my app can't.

I found that I could see and create/edit ODBC data sources by making a copy of the ODBC Data Source tool shortcut, changing it to point to a different path (replace system32 with SYSWOW64), but data sources I create there are somehow hidden from my app.  Is there a way to point my .NET app to a specific Data Source, maybe by creating a File DSN and specifying a full local path, for example?

This is driving me nuts.  Help!

Comment: As far as I know 32 bit programs should work well on 64bit machine.
did you try to you the 32 bit client ? I would address this issue to an oracle forum. It should be clear which client connects to which DB on which platform. nevertheless - 8 is getting pretty old now....

Comment: I did try 9i and 10g (XE) 32-bit clients, with no luck

Answer (score 3):

I finally got a client to work:

http://download.oracle.com/otn/nt/instantclient/10203/instantclient-basiclite-win-x86-64-10.2.0.3.0.zip

Thanks all for the comments and help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the [11g ODP.NET 64 bit clien](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html)t? The ODP.NET client has no problems connecting to Oracle 8/9/10 databases.

Comment: I haven't tried that specific 11g client - I just assumed that if the 11g instant client wouldn't talk to v8, then 11g was just too new.